# Regex to test for a HTML string?

Tags: html, regex

How do I use regex to test if the `Word` part would match bearing in mind that the `Word` might not actually be `Word` but could be `Dogs` or `Cats` for example

```
<span class="GBP"> Word </span>
<span class="AUD"> Word </span>
```

Ie the above should return a match.

But the below returns false

```
<span class="GBP"> Dogs </span>
<span class="AUD"> Cat </span>
```

Comment: which programming language do you use?

Comment: @RaminDarvishov ruby

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to capture the word inside of the span tag, you could use this expression:

[`/<span class=".*?"> (\w+) <\/span>/`](https://regex101.com/r/LlXZmY/1)

Or, if you mean to capture the word when it's not `Dogs` or `Cat`, you can use a [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`/<span class=".*?"> (?!Cat|Dogs)(.*?) <\/span>/`](https://regex101.com/r/LlXZmY/2)